# How to animate ListView refresh in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Blow screenshot is from react-native UIExplorer example. I want to animate list rows adding/removing when data source changed - for example, when entering a keyword in the search box.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try out [`LayoutAnimation`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html):

```
LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
this.setState({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good implementations of react-native refresh components which have animations as a part of it.

One of them is- [react-native-refresher](https://github.com/syrusakbary/react-native-refresher)

I have used this in my projects. It's a great library.

Installation:

```
npm install react-native-refresher --save
```

Usage(check github link for more detailed code):

```
<RefresherListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
      indicator={<LoadingBarIndicator />}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={{padding:10,borderBottomColor: '#CCCCCC', backgroundColor: 'white',borderBottomWidth: 1}}><Text>{rowData}</Text></View>}
/>
```

Also for more details you can have a look at [Animations docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html) by React Native.